# How to add a custom error message in a function in R

Tags: r, function

In the following function, I need to add a custom error message, when the dimension of the vector mu and the dimensions of the matrix sigma do not match.

This is the template for the function I want to use:

```
myfunction = function(mu,sigma) { return(mu %*% sigma)  }
```

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: you can add `if` conditions and `stop` i.e. `if(length(mu) != nrow(sigma)) stop("oh no")`

Comment: "myfunction" = function(mu,sigma){
  if (!dim(mu)[2] == dim(sigma)[1]){
    print("Error: dimensions do not match")
  } else {
    return(mu %*% sigma)  
  }
}